# How to delete expired data with cron job

Tags: mysql, database, cron

I want to auto delete my data on mysql database which has expired date with cron job every 5 minutes.

For example I have a table (TableName) with one of column (ExpDate) as "`2015-04-10 21:30:00`", it's timestamp format type and UTC time zone.

I have tried creat a cron job command like this:

```
*/5 * * * * delete * from TableName where ExpDate > NOW();
```

But it didn't work, I've searched around in SO and elsewhere but have not found a direct answer to this. So, I created this question and hope someone can help me. I am a beginner in cron job, I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: you need your cron to execute a script, which executes the mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Cron doesn't know about SQL commands. Cron knows about running executable commands. This leads us to the answer - you need to either directly call the MySQL command line client in the crontab (probably a bad idea), or you need to write a script that does what you want, and then get cron to execute it.

A sample script would be:

```
USERNAME=[username]
PASSWORD=[password]
DATABASE=[database]
MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql

$MYSQL -u $USERNAME -p$PASSWORD $DATABASE -e "DELETE from ....."
```

You would put this script somewhere safe, because it contains your password. Let's say you called it `purge_expired.sh`, you would need to make it executable like this `chmod +x purge_expired.sh`, and then tell cron to execute that script instead of trying to make it run the SQL commands itself.

Somehow I missed the memo where [MySQL got its own event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html), you might want to use that instead.

An example specific to you would be something like:

```
CREATE EVENT DeleteExpired
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
  DO
    DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ExpDate < NOW();
```

You also need to make sure the `event_scheduler` variable is set to on in order for this to run.